# Using Semantic UI form validation within angular controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, forms, validation, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use the Form Validation of Semantic Ui according to this tutorial 
https://github.com/phillip-haydon/DemoSemanticUIAngular/blob/master/src/DemoWebsite/Views/index.cshtml

with the respective blog entry
http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/10/semantic-ui-and-angularjs-basic-registration-form-with-validation/

If i use .. `$('.ui.form').form({...` within the html file everything works fine , code looks like this

```
<div class="field">
  <label>label</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ngmodel="data.profile.email" placeholder ="you@example.com">
</div>

<script>
 (function ($) {
   console.log($('.ui.form'));
   $('.ui.form').form({
    email: {
      identifier: 'email',
      rules: [{
        type: 'empty',
        prompt: 'Please enter a valid email'
      }]
    },
  }, 
  {
    on: 'blur'
   }
 );
 }(jQuery));
</script>
```

But when I'm trying to achieve the same resultat within my Angular Controller `$('.ui.form').form({` does nothing

I already tested with console logs that in both variants the form element is exactly the same and debugger in chrome dev tools says the "form" method is also the same, but the form vailidation does not work though within the controller.

Comment: using angular and jQuery together is bound to cause you headaches, don't use Jquery with Angular until you really, really understand Angular.

Comment: You have to inject jquery complete before angular, because angular only uses a minified version of jQuery that you can override by inserting your jquery lybrary:  `<script src="pathToJQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` just before your angular library.
Also, it is recommended that any jquery libraries should be used in form of "angular directives".

Comment: In fact, there is already a library of directives for semantic UI that you can use: https://github.com/angularify/angular-semantic-ui

Comment: yes, i included it before angular and jquery is defined and works, because for example I can `console.log($('.ui.form'));`in my controller and everything is ok, except for calling the form method with the rules on that ui form. The weird thing is that `var registrationForm = $($element);`
 and `console.log(registrationForm.form('validate form'));
;` works but not to define the rules with the same approach